# How can I stop NSTableView from saving the current scroll position?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

In my app I have a `NSTableView` in `NSViewController` with a `NSArrayController` provide the content.

It works great, however, when I scroll to some position of tableview, quit app and re-launch it, It will restore the last scroll position. I don't like this behavior, I want it to keep at the top.

I tried to `setAutosaveTableColumns` to NO on NSTableView, it seems not the option I need. It still works the old way.

Does is any option to turn this off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The scroll position is stored by `NSScrollView`, which implements `encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:`/`restoreStateWithCoder:` since OS X Lion.
(Interface Builder automatically wraps a table view in a `NSScrollView`→`NSClipView`→`NSTableView` hierarchy).

To get a scroll view that is scrolled to top after an app relaunch you have several options:

- Turn off view state restoration for the entire window in Interface Builder:
  [image]
- Subclass `NSScrollView` and override `encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:` with an empty implementation (Don't forget to set it as class for your your table view instance in IB):
- Programmatically scroll to top after app relaunch:

  ```
  - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
  {
      [[self.scrollView contentView] scrollToPoint:NSMakePoint(0.0, 0.0)];
      [self.scrollView reflectScrolledClipView:[self.scrollView contentView]];
  }
  ```

Personally I'd go with method 3, because turning off state restoration for the whole window might break some behaviour that your users expect and method 2 [is against Apple's recommendation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:) on calling `[super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:]` when subclassing `NSView`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Finally I choose the second way, because I already subclassed NSScrollView, so it's easy to do that. And I found it is necessary to have an empty `restoreStateWithCoder` too, or the old configuration will be restored.

Comment: @TualatrixChou Same here, I needed up going for method 2 as method 3 didn't work and and method 1 is annoying for the end user.